# Values in textboxes vanish after populating them with sendkeys

Tags: python, selenium, automation, webdriver

I have a text field in my web-page and I am trying to type values in a text-box using `sendkeys`. When I navigate to another element its value getting vanished. I tried long wait for the page load but it couldn't help. When I am trying manually, it's working fine; it fails only while I am using script. I searched for the same problem but I am unable to found any solution regarding this.

```
activeelem = driver.switch_to_active_element() 
time.sleep(2)
activeelem.send_keys("Employee Name")
time.sleep(3)
activeelem.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span/input[@type='checkbox']").click()
```

Note:

1. I am using the current focused element.
2. I tried keys.TAB and other options also.

Any solution on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Its JSTE(Javascript Templating Language) Page.Application is under development and its available in company domain login.

Comment: which version of webdriver? Have you checked if the text field you are scripting against has any events that are triggered on blur that might be clearing the field?

Comment: I am using latest version (2.23.0) of webdriver. and having on change event. *** onchange="updateGridCell(0, {'CellValue':this.value});setCurrentCellName(this.value);" ***